# Amazon S3 and mp4 files

Tags: amazon-web-services, video, browser, amazon-s3, mp4

I have a couple of mp4 videos I have stored in Amazon S3.
When I try to access the file's links from Firefox, they are played automaticlly, but when I try to open the same links in Chrome or IE the files are downloaded and not played.

I also tried setting the content type of the files to video/mp4 with no luck.

Doe's anyone know of a solution to this issue?

Answer (score -1):

Try to store your videos with file_get_contents($videos) to s3 bucket , so that the stored video in bucket can get the original file content and then it can play on any browser